# enable / disable key press event based on focus in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

- If input box is not focused, keypress event should be triggered
- If input box is focused, keypress event should be disabled, and
  typing text should be allowed.
- I've tried focus and blur but that didn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>

</div>

<div class="form">
<form action="" id="submit">
  <input type="text" id="num" number/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="show"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function($){
        //on click
    $('.btn').click(function(){
                var me = $(this);
        $('#show').html(me.text());
    });
    //on keypress
    $(window).keypress(function(k){         
            switch (k.keyCode) {                
                // user presses the "1"
            case 49:
             $('#show').html(1);
               break;           
                // user presses the "2"
            case 50:
            $('#show').html(2);
               break;

                // user presses the "3"
            case 51:
            $('#show').html(3);
               break;
          }
    });

    //on submit
    $('#submit').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#num').val();
      $('#show').html(data);
      $('#num').val('');
    })
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sn13LL3t/)

Comment: Did you try `k.preventDefault();` as the first line in your handler function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking focus property of your input box in keypress event like:

```
if (!$('#num').is(':focus')) {
  switch (k.keyCode) {
    case 49:
      $('#show').html(1);
      break;
      // user presses the "2"
    case 50:
      $('#show').html(2);
      break;
      // user presses the "3"
    case 51:
      $('#show').html(3);
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

You can check it in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn13LL3t/4/) which I have updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEiIXX1pLVAhXMnZQKHSXKB-4QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fevent.preventdefault%2F&usg=AFQjCNExzXG71FDK3YMwK9HzbdkgE3WlXQ) .on input keypress event on default condition

**updated**

For all key prevent in input add `event.preventDefault()` in first line of the keypress function

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sn13LL3t/2/)

```
$(window).keypress(function(k) {
    k.preventDefault() //its prevent all keyinput
  switch (k.keyCode) {

    case 49:
      $('#show').html(1);
      break;
      // user presses the "2"
    case 50:
      $('#show').html(2);
      break;

      // user presses the "3"
    case 51:
      $('#show').html(3);
      break;
    default:
      k.preventDefault() //its prevent keypress other than 1,2,3
  }
});
```

Comment: see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sn13LL3t/2/ .you need prevent all key input or see the updated answer